# regular expression replace two group

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have pattern like : `<[a-zA-Z][^>]*(?:poster|src)=(['\"])([^'\"]+)\\1[^>]*>`
here i want to replace the value of src or poster attributes.

It is okey for

```
<video src='srcVal' />
```

and

```
<video poster='posterVal' src='srcVal' />
```

but for

```
<video poster='posterVal' src='srcVal' />
```

only changes src value, due to `matcher.group(2)` returning only `srcVal`.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String html = "<video poster='posterVal' src='srcVal' />";
        Pattern resourcePattern = Pattern.compile("<[a-zA-Z][^>]*(?:poster|src)=(['\"])([^'\"]+)\\1[^>]*>");
        Matcher matcher = resourcePattern.matcher(html);
        int last = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(matcher.find()) {
            String path = matcher.group(2) + "Changed";
            sb.append( html.substring(last, matcher.start(2)) + path );
            last = matcher.end(2);
        }
        sb.append(html.substring(last));
        System.out.println(sb);
        //outputs <video poster='posterVal' src='srcValChanged' />
        //expecting <video poster='posterValChanged' src='srcValChanged' />
    }
}
```

Does any body has an idea how to do this?

Comment: try looking here: [Java Regex](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: I would not recommend using regexps when you are concerned with the structure of the language rather than the precise representation as text.  That is, you are parsing an XML dialect and in XML the order of attributes does not matter - but regexps cannot easily represent 'order does not matter'. Use a real XML library, there are very many to choose from.

Comment: They cannot easily, but still, they can. Lookaheads and conditional regex are 2 tools that can be used to achieve such things.

Comment: I accept suggetion of @drquicksilver. I will use an xml parser and xpath to alter values. As a result it is not possible such a thing with a single pattern. Like in tutorial recommeded by gangqinlaohu, it can be achived by using one more pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do this with regex, but you can try such a thing:

```
<[a-zA-Z]*[^>]*(?:(poster)|src)=(['\"])([^'\"]+)\\2(?(1)[^>]*(?:src=(['\"])([^'\"]+)\\4)?[^>]*|[^>]*(?:poster=(['\"])([^'\"]+)\\6)?[^>]*)>
```

Though I don't have time to test it as of now, sorry.

**Edit:**
Less performance-oriented:

```
<[a-zA-Z]*(?=(?:[^>]*?poster=['\"]([^'\"]+))?)(?=(?:[^>]*?src=['\"]([^'\"]+))?)[^>]*(?:poster|src)[^>]*>
```

If you only want to match video tags, change it to (as it'd greatly improve it):

```
<video(?=(?:[^>]*?poster=['\"]([^'\"]+))?)(?=(?:[^>]*?src=['\"]([^'\"]+))?)[^>]*(?:poster|src)[^>]*>
```

**Explanation:** (as I guess it must look quite disturbing)

We're using 2 lookaheads to capture what's interesting. Lookaheads will allow us to check twice what comes ahead, therefore ignoring the order. However, those lookaheads must always work (using * and ? to make sure of that), but still being greedy, while being lazy (what?): we have to stop as soon as we see poster/src, but go far enough to catch those. `.*?a?` will always catch nothing. So we use here `(?:.*?a)?`. The behavior here is to try to catch the *a* with laziness, while if it fails it's not a problem.
The last part of the regex is to make sure we catch only tags with a poster or a src attribute, as our lookaheads only do that catching and certainly can't be used to do that.

Note that I removed the check for your attributes, as anyway it was useless.

Comment: I think i understand how you want to do, but it complains about (?(1)...) part. Thanks.

Comment: Damn, I thought Java supported conditional regex. I'll put more thought into it.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is with the `[^>]*` near the start of your expression.  Because `*` is greedy this will eat up as many characters as it can while still allowing the rest of the expression to match, so given

```
<video poster='posterVal' src='srcVal' />
```

the `[^>]*` will gobble `ideo poster='posterVal'` up to and including the space before `src=`.

I would approach it differently, rather than trying to write a regex that matches the whole tag just write one that matches the attributes you're interested in, and replace *all* matches of that expression

```
html.replaceAll("\\b((?:poster|src)=)(['\"])([^'\"]+)\\1", "$1$2$3Changed$2")
```

But as other posters have commented it would be much more sensible to use a proper parser that understands the language rather than trying to manipulate the textual representation with regular expressions.

Comment: That's not so much his problem. He wants to capture both, whatever the order.

Comment: if i have an html like <span>src="my.png"</span>, it will change plain text, not only element attributes.